# Подсчёт в БД не пустых значений

Tags: php, mysql

Почему считает всех, пустых и не пустых?

```
   <?php
   include('db.php');
   $userssitep=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `DUser` WHERE Did IS NOT NULL",$db) or      
   die(mysql_error());
   $usersreviewp = mysql_num_rows($userssitep);
   echo $usersreviewp;
   ?>
```

**UPD** Спасибо, походу нужно проходить курс реабилитации от уроков Е.Попова

Answer (score 3, accepted):

может потому что null - это не пустые, а null? а тебе надо попробовать запрос

> SELECT * FROM `DUser` WHERE Did = '';

а для подсчета

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `DUser` WHERE Did = '';
```

Comment: @Gorets см ответ @Palmervan

      select count(*) from `DUser` where trim(ifnull(did, ''));

Answer (score 1):

**A.5.3 Проблемы со значением NULL**

Концепция NULL-значения часто вводит в заблуждение новичков в SQL, которые считают, что NULL - то же, что и пустая строка "". Это ошибка! Например, следующие команды совершенно различны:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO my_table (phone) VALUES (NULL);
mysql> INSERT INTO my_table (phone) VALUES ("");
```

Обе команды вставляют значение в столбец phone, но первая - значение NULL, а вторая - пустую строку. Смысл первого можно передать как `номер телефона неизвестен'', смысл второго -`у нее нет телефона''.

[Продолжить изучать документацию...](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Problems_with_NULL.html)

Comment: наверно наоборот в смысле